# Asignar valores de un array a variables

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente array

```
$resultados=array (
              0 => '21.52',
              1 => '29555.35',
              2 => 6360.31,
              3 => '21.45',
              4 => '42423.50',
              5 => 9099.84,
            )
```

Dependiendo de la clave(0 a 5) quisiera  aplicar  su valor a una variable
Por ejemplo.

```
foreach($resultados as $key=>$valor){If($key=0){$variable1=$resultado[$key].$valor;}
```

De manera que el resultado sería $variable1='21.52'

Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es fácil, dependiendo del valor sólo has de acceder al elemento del array:

```
$VarPos2 = $resultados[2];

echo $VarPos2;
```

Si quieres que tu variable contenga el valor de la clave 0 pues sólo cambia dicho valor:

```
$VarPos0 = $resultados[0];

echo $VarPos0;
```